# Multi-dimensional array indexing using a single dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional array, `X` of size `(500,10)` and  a single dimensional index array `Y` whose size is `500` whose each entry is an index of correct value column of corresponding row of X, e.g, `y(0)` is 2 then it means column 2 of first row of X is correct, similarly `y(3) = 4` means Row 3 and Col 4 of `X` has correct value.

I want to get all the correct values from X using index array Y without using any loops, i.e, using vectorization and in this case the output should be `(500,1)`. But when i do `X[:,y]` then it gives output `(500,500)`. Can someone help me how to correctly index array X using Y, plz.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Please could you add some code and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Are you using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)?  Things like that are basically what it was made for.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your inputs and outputs. Could you give concrete (but truncated) examples of what `X` and `Y` might look like, and what you'd expect your output to look like?

Comment: And why do you want to avoid loops? It seems like this data structure would require at least one pass over the data to extract the correct values into a new list.

Comment: It's not clear you understand that arrays are indexed from 0 in Python, so `y(3)` would likely mean Row 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is multidimensional list-of-locations indexing:

```
import numpy as np

ncol = 10  # 10 in your case
nrow = 500  # 500 in your case
# just creating some test data:
x = np.arange(ncol*nrow).reshape(nrow,ncol)
y = (ncol * np.random.random_sample((nrow, 1))).astype(int)

print(x)
print(y)
print(x[np.arange(nrow),y.T].T)
```

The syntax is explained [here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing#Multidimensional_list-of-locations_indexing). You basically need an array of indices for each dimension. In the first dimension this is simply [0,...,500] in your case and the second dimension is your y-array. We need to transpose it (.T), because it has to have the same shape as the first and the output array. The second transposition is not really needed, but gives you the shape you want.

**EDIT:**

The question of performance came up and I tried the three methods mentioned so far. You'll need [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) to run the following with

```
kernprof -l -v tmp.py
```

where tmp.py is:

```
import numpy as np

@profile
def calc(x,y):
    z = np.arange(nrow)
    a = x[z,y.T].T  # mine, with the suggested speed up
    b = x[:,y].diagonal().T  # Christoph Terasa
    c = np.array([i[j] for i, j in zip(x, y)])  # tobias_k

    return (a,b,c)

ncol = 5  # 10 in your case
nrow = 10  # 500 in your case

x = np.arange(ncol*nrow).reshape(nrow,ncol)
y = (ncol * np.random.random_sample((nrow, 1))).astype(int)

a, b, c = calc(x,y)
print(a==b)
print(b==c)
```

The output for my python 2.7.6:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    3                                           @profile
    4                                           def calc(x,y):
    5         1            4      4.0      0.1      z = np.arange(nrow)
    6         1           35     35.0      0.8      a = x[z,y.T].T
    7         1         3409   3409.0     76.7      b = x[:,y].diagonal().T
    8       501          995      2.0     22.4      c = np.array([i[j] for i, j in zip(x, y)])
    9                                           
    10         1            1      1.0      0.0      return (a,b,c)
```

Where %Time or Time are the relevant columns. I don't know how to profile memory consumption, someone else would have to do that.
For now it looks like my solution is the fastest for the requested dimensions.

Comment: This likely uses less memory than my solution. If you have do to this multiple times, you can also speed it up by assigning `np.arange(nrow)` to a variable.

Comment: My solution is only the fastest with small arrays. I profiled using ipython's %timeit for a (500,10) shape, and my solution is already 1.5 times slower than the list comprehension. Your solution, @StefanS, on the other hand is at least 20 times faster than the list comprehension on my machine. Calculating the whole NxN matrix, while only being interested in the diagonal becomes inefficient really fast...

Comment: True, it was stupid of me not to use the real dimensions. I'll go and fix that.

Comment: @StefanS Thank you very much for the great answer.

Answer (score 4):

While not really intuitive from a syntactic perspective

```
X[:,Y].diagonal()[0]
```

will give you the values you're looking for. The fancy indexing selects from each row of `X` all values in `Y`, and `diagonal` selects only those at the indexes where i == j. The indexing with `[0]` at the end just flattens the 2d array.

Comment: This indeed works, however, I wonder whether this is faster/more efficient than using a loop, as this will still temporarily create a 500x500 array.

Comment: Try it yourself. I'd suspect that this is still faster than looping, at least for 500 elements. And I'm certain there is a more clever and clearer way to do it, but I can just now not come up with it.

Comment: I tried, and for 500 rows, a simple `np.array([x[y] for x, y in zip(X, Y)])` seems to be 5-10 times faster.

Comment: Curious. I wonder who keeps upvoting my answer, then.

`In [137]: %timeit X[:,Y].diagonal()
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop

In [138]: %timeit array([x[y] for x,y in zip(X,Y)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop`

Comment: @tobias_k I profiled it as well, and the zip method seems to be slower for me.

Comment: This solution is not good because indexing by `X[:,Y]` will create a new array, which is a slow process. The solution by @StefanS will only create a view into the array, which is much, much faster.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need an helper vector `R` to index the rows

```
In [50]: X = np.arange(24).reshape((6,4))

In [51]: Y = np.random.randint(0,4,6)

In [52]: R = np.arange(6)

In [53]: Y
Out[53]: array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0])

In [54]: X[R,Y]
Out[54]: array([ 0,  6, 10, 12, 17, 20])
```

for your use case

```
X_y = X[np.arange(500), Y]
```

---

*Edit*

I forgot to mention, if you want a 2D result you can obtain such a result using a dummy index

```
X_y_2D = X[np.arange(500), Y, None]
```

Comment: It seems like this is basically the same as @StefanS solution, just without the double `.T`

Comment: The first .T is not need here because your Y has a different shape than my y and the output has shape (1,500), not (500,1) as was requested.

Comment: @tobias_k So it seems that the problem has a unique, elegant, obvious solution... I spent a little more time arriving (all by myself) at it but my implementation is a little different and also the explanation is simpler.

Comment: @gboffi Thank you for the kind help.